# Left Outer Join returning results to be excluded

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like

```
WITH a AS ( SELECT * 
              FROM inventory_tagalongs 
             WHERE TagAlong_ItemNum <> 'bokiwi2'
          )

SELECT inventory.itemnum
     , inventory.itemname
     , inventory.ItemType,inventory.dept_id  
  FROM inventory 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN a 
    ON inventory.itemnum = a.itemnum
  JOIN departments
    ON inventory.dept_id = departments.dept_id
  JOIN categories 
    ON departments.subtype = categories.cat_id AND categories.description = 'vapors'
```

in which i am trying to exclude `a`'s results from the lower `syntax` but the results return are exactly the same whether or not `left outer join.....` is there or not.

Do i have my syntax incorrect here?

Comment: you need to ass where `a.primaryKey is null` or a better way would be to use `exists`. [This answer explains a slight](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists) performance increase too

Comment: *you need to __add__ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good afternoon.  Please try this:

```
select 
   inventory.itemnum
   , inventory.itemname
   , inventory.ItemType
   , inventory.dept_id 
from inventory 
join departments on inventory.dept_id=departments.dept_id 
join categories on departments.subtype=categories.cat_id and categories.description='vapors'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  select 1 from inventory_tagalongs B where inventory.itemnum = b.itemnum 
  AND B.TagAlong_ItemNum <>'bokiwi2');
```

The CTE overthought the issue a bit.  This accomplishes the goal with easier-to-read code and should perform better as well.

Thanks, John.

Comment: I tried both and this does execute more quickly. I did overthink that a bit lol. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get results that don't have the tag, your logic is inverted.  You want:

```
SELECT i.itemnum, i.itemname, i.ItemType, i.dept_id  
FROM inventory i JOIN
     departments d
     ON i.dept_id = d.dept_id JOIN
     categories c
     ON d.subtype = c.cat_id AND
        c.description = 'vapors' LEFT OUTER JOIN
     a 
     ON i.itemnum = a.itemnum
WHERE a.itemnum IS NULL;
```

You don't need a CTE for this at all.  It would usually be written as:

```
WITH a AS (

    )
SELECT i.itemnum, i.itemname, i.ItemType, i.dept_id  
FROM inventory i JOIN
     departments d
     ON i.dept_id = d.dept_id JOIN
     categories c
     ON d.subtype = c.cat_id AND
        c.description = 'vapors' LEFT OUTER JOIN
     inventory_tagalongs it
     ON i.itemnum = it.itemnum AND it.TagAlong_ItemNum = 'bokiwi2' 
WHERE a.itemnum IS NULL;
```

And -- as mentioned in another answer -- `NOT EXISTS` is another typical way to approach this problem.